# Explicitly highliting edges in Google Sketchup

Tags: 3d, drawing, collada, sketchup

How do I explicitly highlight edges in Google Sketchup?

If I have an object with "invisible" edges, for example the curved sides of a cylinder, how do I explicitly draw these edges?

This is basically for when exporting to Collada as it has a  tag, but I guess it is the same for all formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question. You mention "highlighting" edges, then how to explicitly "draw" hidden/soft/smooth edge?
You want to unhide/unsoft/unsmooth them? Or you want to select them?

You say you need it for exporting to collada - can you elaborate to exactly what you are trying to do, what isn't working as expected and what the expected results are?

Comment: Lets say I have created a barrel. You don't normaly see the edges that make up the curved side or the two circles on top and bottom. What I want to do is explicitly draw some of these edges, for example the two circles that makes the top and bottom, but leave the other edges undrawn for a smooth effect.

Comment: When you create a barrel in SketchUp you PushPull a circle - the edges of the top and bottom face of the barres are visible and the perpendicular edges are soft/smooth. This sounds like the result you want to achieve. You seem to indicate that you have everything hidden - which would not be the default behaviour of SketchUp? (Have you got some screenshots to describe this?) Also, how have you created the barrel, manually modelling or by Ruby Script?

Comment: Your first part is correct. When you create a circle and pull it up you can see the edges of the top and bottom face. But this is just how SketchUp draws it. If I save or export the barrel object those lines are not exported as lines. What I want to do is select those edges and tell SketchUp to do just that. So when I export the barrel object, it is exported as the normal barrel plus lines for the edges I want "highlighted".

Comment: Ah - now I gotcha. Have you enabled this option in SketchUp's collada export options? http://sketchup.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140409 - "*Export Edges* The Export Edges checkbox is used to maintain the appearance of a model with edges visible. Note that stand-alone edges are always exported. "